# Visual Studio 2017 Crystal Reports Error Load Report Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I will admit first and foremost that his is probably a lack of knowledge issue.  As I'm not finding documentation on "how to" deploy a crystal report webpage from visual studio 2017 to a Windows 2012 R2 server. I assumed it would be the same as any other webpage, but apparently I'm missing something.

So this is just a proof of concept so it is BASIC.  I mean zero programming just using the tools given by the IDE and crystal reports SDK.

I created a basic no frills website, added a crystal reports viewer, set up the Crystal Report Source to point at the report in a reports folder and when that didn't work to a place on the HDD ( Here I think is the problem ).  This set up works locally with no issues.  However from the server it throws the Error: Load Report Failed..

Now I realized at one point that the report itself was not publishing, so I set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always".. this does not work.  So I right click the report in the Solution Explorer and published it.. it's there now, yet the error still comes up. I would guess because it points directly to the local copy on my system.

I thought this has to be a rights issue, so for testing I gave Everyone full control of that reports folder with List folder content all the way down to it.  Still no joy..

To defelect the obvious question, yes I have already checked 32 bit and 64 bit on the application pool and I have installed the Runtime on the server, i have tried both 32 bit and 64 bit there as well.

So educated assistance would be very helpful here. Thank you.

Comment: Step up your game and start using SSRS is what I would suggest , this will make your life much easier in regards to creating reports.

Comment: I don't create the reports.  These are all created by someone that shouldn't be creating reports, but hey I'm just the IT guy right? What do I know?

Comment: Could you deploy the reports to the server (make a folder on the server for the reports and then make sure the account the webpage is running on can see the folder)?

Comment: Deploy it to which server @Rich?

Comment: The one you mentioned: the webserver. Or a file area that the webserver can 'see'. As a test, log in to the webserver using the web server's service account, and see if you can then 'see' the path the reports are in. If not, put it in one that the webserver can 'see'.

Comment: Yes that was already tried, as stated above that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort out the load report failed error using below URL

http://remiware.co/2015/07/08/solving-the-load-report-failed-error/

Comment: Yes.. please read the part where I said that it works locally just not on the server..

Comment: yes that why i ask you check the stuff using http://remiware.co/2015/07/08/solving-the-load-report-failed-error/  as your local and server configuration are different.